# MySQL perform subquery if count is zero

Tags: mysql

I have three tables: `monthly_revenue`, `currencies` and `foreign_exchange`.

### monthly_revenue table

```
|------------------------------------------------------|
| id | product_id | currency_id | value | month | year |
|------------------------------------------------------|
| 1  | 1          | 1           | 100   | 1     | 2015 |
| 2  | 1          | 2           | 125   | 1     | 2015 |
| 3  | 1          | 3           | 115   | 1     | 2015 |
| 4  | 1          | 1           | 100   | 2     | 2015 |
| 5  | 1          | 2           | 125   | 2     | 2015 |
| 6  | 1          | 3           | 115   | 2     | 2015 |
|------------------------------------------------------|
```

### foreign_exchange table

```
|---------------------------------------|
| id | base | target | rate | rate_date |
|---------------------------------------|
| 1  | GBP  | USD    | 1.6  |2015-01-01 |
| 2  | GBP  | USD    | 1.62 |2015-01-15 |
| 3  | GBP  | USD    | 1.61 |2015-01-31 |
| 4  | EUR  | USD    | 1.2  |2015-01-01 |
| 5  | EUR  | USD    | 1.4  |2015-01-15 |
| 6  | EUR  | USD    | 1.4  |2015-01-31 |
| 7  | GBP  | EUR    | 1.4  |2015-01-01 |
| 8  | GBP  | EUR    | 1.45 |2015-01-15 |
| 9  | GBP  | EUR    | 1.44 |2015-01-31 |
|---------------------------------------|
```

From this, we can see the average fx rates:

- GBP > USD in January is 1.61
- EUR > USD in January is 1.33
- GBP > EUR in January is 1.43

No rates are available for USD as a base currency, and no rates are available for February.

### currencies table

```
|-----------|
| id | name |
|-----------|
| 1  | GBP  |
| 2  | USD  |
| 3  | EUR  |
|-----------|
```

### What i'm trying to achieve

Each row within the `monthly_revenue` table can have a different `currency_id`, as orders are placed is different currencies. I want to see all revenue for a given month, in a common currency. So, rather than looking at all revenue in January in GBP, and then separately looking at all revenue in January in USD, I'd like to get one value for all revenue in January - converted to USD (for example).

This can be calculated for each row, using the following (using January for this example):

revenue value **x** average fx rate for January between base and target currency

If I have 50 orders in January, in 4 different currencies, this let's me see all revenue in any single currency.

### Example - get all revenue in January, in USD

This should return:

```
|------------------------------------------------------|
| id | product_id | currency_id | value | month | year |
|------------------------------------------------------|
| 1  | 1          | 1           | 100   | 1     | 2015 |
| 2  | 1          | 2           | 125   | 1     | 2015 |
| 3  | 1          | 3           | 115   | 1     | 2015 |
|------------------------------------------------------|
```

However, rows 1 and 3 are not in USD (these are GBP, and EUR respectively).

What I'd like to see is each row returned with the average FX rate that is being converted to, and a `converted` column. For example:

```
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| id | prod_id | currency_id | value | month | year | fx_avg | converted  |
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 1  | 1       | 1           | 100   | 1     | 2015 | 1.61   | 161        |
| 2  | 1       | 2           | 125   | 1     | 2015 | 1      | 125        |
| 3  | 1       | 3           | 115   | 1     | 2015 | 1.33   | 152.95     |
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

### Where I'm at

I can currently get the basic calculation done using the query below, but a couple of key features are lacking:

- If there is no FX rate available (for example for future dates where of course an FX rate isn't available) then the entire row is ignored. What I'd like in this instance is for the latest month's average to be used.
- If the calculation is being performed where the target currency is the same as the base currency, the entire row is ignored (as there is no record in the FX table where the base equals the target). In this instance, the rate should be hard defined as 1.

### Query so far

```
SELECT 
    r.value * IFNULL(AVG(fx.rate),1) as converted, AVG(fx.rate) as averageFx, 
    r.*, fx.*
FROM 
    foreign_exchange fx, monthly_revenue r, order_headers h
WHERE 
    fx.base IN (SELECT name FROM currencies WHERE id = r.currency_id) AND 
    r.order_header_id = h.id AND 
    fx.target = 'USD' AND 
    MONTH(fx.rate_date) = r.month AND
    YEAR(fx.rate_date) = r.year AND
    r.year = 2015
GROUP BY r.id
ORDER BY month ASC
```

If there are no records available for FX, it looks like a separate subquery should be performed to get the average of the latest month's rates.

Any input would be appreciated. If any further info is required, please post a comment.

Thanks.

**Edit** [Here is a SQFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/33def/2) which has the example schemas and the code which highlights the issue.

Comment: "by multiplying the record's value by the average FX rate for the month the revenue was generated" - is that a standard statistical method?!?!

Comment: No, but it's a simplification for the purposes of this question. The wording in the question is a little off however, i'll revise it.

Comment: OK, and can you provide an sqlfiddle of same?

Comment: Sure, please see the link in the edited post.

Comment: Well done. This is pretty much now a model of how a question of this kind should be asked on SO.

Comment: The currencies table is a bit annoying, isn't it? GBP would seem to be a satisfactory PK. :-(

Comment: Indeed. Did you have any luck?

Comment: Ah, overwhelmed with real work at the moment - but I'll get back to it when I can (assumning no one else answers). I'll remove my answer for the time being so others can see that this is unanswered.

Comment: I think you looking for `coalesce(t.field, (select field2 form t2 where... limit 1))`

Comment: @BigPun : please test my query and let me know whether it solves your problem.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an approximation of a function that computes your exchange for a given currency and start of month:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION MonthRate(IN _curr CHAR(3) CHARACTER SET ascii,
                          IN _date DATE)
    RETURNS FLOAT
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    -- Note:  _date must be the first of some month, such as '2015-02-01'
    DECLARE _avg FLOAT;
    DECLARE _prev FLOAT;
    -- First, try to get the average for the month:
    SELECT AVG(rate) INTO _avg FROM foreign_exchange
        WHERE base = _curr
          AND target = 'USD'
          AND rate_date >= _date
          AND rate_date  < _date + INTERVAL 1 MONTH;
    IF _avg IS NOT NULL THEN
        RETURN _avg;
    END;
    -- Fall back onto the last rate before the month:
    SELECT rate INTO _prev
        FROM foreign_exchange
        WHERE base = _curr
          AND target = 'USD'
          AND rate_date < _date
        ORDER BY _date
        LIMIT 1;
    IF _prev IS NOT NULL THEN
        RETURN _prev;
    END;
    SELECT "Could not get value -- ran off start of Rates table";
END;
DELIMITER ;
```

There are probably syntax errors, etc.  But hopefully you can work with it.

It should be easy to call the function from the rest of the code.

For performance, this would be beneficial:

```
INDEX(base, target, rate_date, rate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a view :

```
 create view avg_rate as
   select base, target, year(fx.rate_date) year, month(fx.rate_date) month,
          avg(rate) avg_rate 
   from  foreign_exchange group by base, target
```

Join it twice, once for current month, and once for previous

```
 select r.id, r.month, 
        r.value * avg(coalesce(cr.avg_rate, pr.avg_rate, 1)) converted,
        avg(coalesce(cr.avg_rate, pr.avg_rate), 0) rate

 from monthly_revenue r, avg_rate cr, avg_rate pr, order_headers h

 where
  r.year = 2015 and
  cr.year = r.year and cr.month = r.month  and cr.target='USD' and 
  pr.year = r.year and pr.month = r.month - 1  and pr.target='USD' and
  r.order_header_id = h.id
 group by r.id
 order by r.month
```

Also I personally don't like this way of writing query and prefer to using explicit joins as you group conditions logically and don't have a mess in where clause. i.e.:

```
 ... 
 from monthly_revenue r
    inner join order_headers h on r.order_header_id = h.id
    left join avg_rate cr on cr.year = r.year and cr.month = r.month  and cr.target='USD'
    left join avg_rate pr on pr.year = r.year and pr.month = r.month - 1 and pr.target='USD'

 where r.year = 2015
```

Comment: Can you provide an SQFIddle of this? I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: @BigPun http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/611e1/9 check this. Note that you didnt have proper group operation in your latest query ( you group by r.id but uses r.value without aggregation, so i added sum )

Comment: Your query almost accomplishes what I need, but not quite. I've modified it - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/604fc/1 but it's extremely inefficient. Your version only provides the previous month's average rate - but if i'm reporting for 3 months ahead, then this wouldn't work. Take a look at my update to see

Comment: @BigPun That is not the same query i did. and it mostly inefficient because of your additional subquery. See - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/604fc/2 remove it and it is already half the time. Another issue is that since you are using `month(d)` it cannot use index on the column. you can improve speed by a lot by adding two columns to foreign_exchange  - year and month.

Comment: Agreed, it's inefficient but it enables me to use an fx rate for up to a year ago which was one of the requirements. Your query fetches just the average of the previous month. Take the scenario: we're now in August, but I want to see all subscription revenue for 2015. There are no fx rates available for Sep, Oct, Nov and Dec so your query would default to '1' which is incorrect. My modification solves that at the expense of performance - which is what I'm looking for a proper fix for.

Comment: @BigPun that is not what I am talking about. There are two issues with the query - extra subquery in every join , which i fixed - see my sqlfiddle link, and the fact that indexes can't be used in your query because of `month(x)` construct. in order to make your query perform better (even with 12 joins) you need precalculate month and year , so you 'll be able to use index on foreign_exchange table. or you can upgrade to mysql 5.7 and use calculated columns.

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6a41a/1

This fiddle based on your original one but I added some rate values for February and March to test and show how it works.

```
 SELECT t.*,
  IF(@first=t.id, @flag := @flag+1,@flag:=1) `flag`,
  @first:=t.id
FROM
(SELECT 
    coalesce(fx.rate,1) `rate`, (r.value * coalesce(fx.rate,1)) as converted, 
    r.*, fx.base,fx.target, fx.avg_date, fx.rate frate
FROM 
    monthly_revenue r
LEFT JOIN
    currencies
ON r.currency_id = currencies.id
LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT AVG(rate) `rate`, 
 `base`, 
 `target`,
 STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('1/',MONTH(rate_date),'/',YEAR(rate_date)), '%d/%m/%Y') avg_date
 FROM foreign_exchange 
 GROUP BY `base`, `target`, `avg_date`
  ) fx
ON currencies.name = fx.base
   AND fx.target = 'USD'
   AND fx.avg_date <= STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('1/',r.month,'/',r.year), '%d/%m/%Y')
ORDER BY r.id, fx.avg_date DESC) t
HAVING `flag` = 1
```

and if you need records just for specific month you can add `WHERE` before `ORDER` like this:

```
WHERE r.month = 1 and r.year = 2015
ORDER BY r.id, fx.avg_date DESC) t
```

Comment: The average rate doesn't seem to be correct. In my local dataset, I have revenue records for 2015, 08 with fx rates for the current month, but the average used is for 2012-11-01 (incidentally, one of the first rates available for the given currency)

Comment: I don't understand your point, could you provide corrected fiddle with your dataset and point the wrong record returned please?

Answer (score 0):

You may test this query on the fiddle link you provided : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/33def/2

```
select id,product_id,currency_id,currency_name,
    value,month,year,@prev_fx_avg:=ifnull(fx_avg,@prev_fx_avg) fx_avg,
    value*@prev_fx_avg as converted 
from (SELECT 
    r.id,r.product_id,r.currency_id,c.name as currency_name,
    r.value,r.month,r.year,if(c.name="USD",1,temp.avg_rate) as fx_avg

FROM 
    monthly_revenue r
    left join currencies c on r.currency_id=c.id
    left join

    (select base , avg(rate) as avg_rate, MONTH(fx.rate_date) month,
     YEAR(fx.rate_date) year
     from foreign_exchange fx
     where target="USD"
     group by base,target,MONTH(fx.rate_date),
    YEAR(fx.rate_date)) temp on(r.month=temp.month and r.year=temp.year and c.name=temp.base)

    group by r.id
    order by r.currency_id,r.month ASC, r.year ASC) final,(select @prev_fx_avg:=-1) temp2;
```